# Python - Count occurences of one dictionary list with another

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have two lists contatining dictionaries, such as `[ {'one':1}, {'two':2}, {'three':3} ]` and `[ {'a':1}, {'b':1}, {'c':1}, {'d':3}, {'e':3} ]`.

I want to count the occurence of each id in the first list with the second. The result should be similar to: `one = 3, two = 0, three = 2`.

Comment: Why do you have a single key-value pair inside each dict in the lists? That's very inefficient

Comment: The actual data will continue being developed and thus will not be as simplified as this. But the matching will occur based only on the one attribute and thus, what is needed for this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using List Comprehensions

**Code**

```
# Data
lst1 = [ {'one':1}, {'two':2}, {'three':3} ]

lst2 = [ {'a':1}, {'b':1}, {'c':1}, {'d':3}, {'e':3} ]

# List of values in dictionaries of lst2
values = [v for d in lst2 for k, v in d.items()]

# count of occurrences in values array by 
# key for each dictionary value in lst1
# I assume dictionary keys in lst1 are unique
# since they correspond to ids, otherwise we could make the output
# counts = [{k:values.count(v)} ...]
counts = {k:values.count(v) for d in lst1 for k, v in d.items()}

print(counts)
```

**Output**

```
{'one': 3, 'two': 0, 'three': 2}
```

Comment: What would d.items() represent? Did you mean to write lst1.items()?
Pardon the beginners level knowledge in python.
EDIT:
Also, I saw this in another answer with this method or using a collections.Counter. After receiving this dictionary of key pair values, how would I access each? counts[0], counts[1], ..., counts[n]?

Comment: @MariosYiannakou--hi Marios.  Note I have: `for d in lst1 for k, v in d.items()`, which makes d iterate over the dictionaries in lst1.  So d.items() are the name,value pairs of items in dictionary d.  There is no lst1.items since its a list, not a dictionary.